# Converting text file to UTF-8 on Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, utf-8

I need to convert a text file to UTF-8 format via Windows command prompt. This needs to be done on another machine and I do not have rights to install software on that machine. I need something like:

```
c:\notepad   source-file target-file --encoding option
```

Is there a Windows command prompt utility which can do it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

#### I need to convert a text file to utf-8 format via windows command prompt

You can easily do this with PowerShell:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 test-utf8.txt
```

This method will convert to UTF-8-BOM

---

#### Further Reading

- [Convert from most encodings to utf8 with powershell](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Convert_from_most_encodings_to_utf8_with_powershell)

Comment: Additionally, you need to switch to powershell  in order to execute the command and then exit it to go back to windows command prompt.

Comment: Indeed. Or run it directly in a PowerShell shell.

Comment: @DavidPostill any idea how we can convert more than one file i.e batch file processing with the same command line ?

Comment: @vibs2006 Use a `ForEach` loop. See [ForEach - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html).

Comment: Will this method convert to plain UTF-8 or UTF-8-BOM?

Comment: `Get-Content -ReadCount 5000 -Raw .\test.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 test-utf8.txt` can convert huge files (over GB) very fast.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to define a different name for the ouptut file. Otherwise you get a "used by another process" error message.

Comment: but if I want to convert multiples .txt files, from a folder+subfolders, what is the command?

Comment: @JustMe See my comment above - use a `ForEach` loop

Comment: yes, but is much easy to put the entire formula here

Comment: @JustMe I'm not going to do that for you.

Comment: please, thanks. Not just for me, for all those that need the solution.

Comment: Strangely, it put spaces in-between characters when I ran this (I was using it on a .tex file, which is just a text file). Seems to be because it's converting from UTF16-LE (related to using the latexdiff tool on Windows).

Answer (score 10):

Use `iconv` from GNUWin32 pack. It is much faster, especially if your files are about or more than 1 Gb.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f cp1251 -t utf-8 source.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: what does the `cp1251` flag do ?

Comment: it's the input encoding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251

Comment: Git bash works also:
iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8 ./s.txt > t.txt

Answer (score 3):

Here is for each convert *.text file to *.sql file:

```
foreach ($file in get-ChildItem *.txt) {
    Echo $file.name
    Get-Content $file | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 ("$file.name" +".sql")
 }
```

Comment: after run some sql file, sometime error, I decided to using linux with iconv command =))

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the command prompt as follows:

```
powershell -command "Get-Content .\test.txt" > test-utf8.txt
```

It turns out that piping the output to a file from the command prompt saves as utf-8.

Comment: but if I want to convert multiples .txt files, from a folder+subfolders, what is the command?

Answer (score 0):

POWERSHELL: # Assumes Windows PowerShell, use -Encoding utf8BOM with PowerShell Core. For multiple files:

**FIRST SOLUTION:**

```
$files = Get-ChildItem c:\Folder1\ -Filter *.txt 

foreach ($file in $files) {

    Get-Content $file.FullName | Set-Content "E:\Temp\Destination\$($file.Name)" -Encoding utf8BOM

}
```

**OR, SECOND SOLUTION (for multiple files):**

```
get-item C:\Folder1*.* | foreach-object {get-content -Encoding utf8BOM $_ | out-file ("C:\Folder1" + $_.Name) -encoding default}
```

**OR, THE THIRD SOLUTION: (only for 2 files)**

```
$a = "C:/Folder1/TEST_ro.txt"
 $b = "C:/Folder1/TEST_ro-2.txt"
 (Get-Content -path $a) | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8BOM -Path $b
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to batch convert several files (e.g.: all `*.txt` files in folder and sub-folders):

```
dir *.txt -Recurse | foreach {
  # May remove the line below if you are confident
  Copy-Item $_ $_.bkp
  
  # Note that since we are reading and saving to the same file,
  # we need to enclose the command in parenthesis so it fully executes 
  # (reading all content and closing the file) before proceeding
  (Get-Content $_) | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 $_
}
```