# Convert UTF-16 LE to UTF-8 in windows via command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, encoding, unicode, utf-8

(question re-written to be more useful)

I have a batch script which will interact with command line programs, take their output, and then perform decisions based on that output.

One of the programs I need to interact with is a fairly old one, so I am stuck with it's quirks. When I pipe it's output to a text file, that text file is in the UTF-16 LE encoding.

Here's how I do that:

```
program -parameter > resultat.txt
```

Under Windows 7, this encoding seems to be troublesome for cmd/batch work, because you cannot read the contents of such a text file into a variable.

Here is an example, (this only uses the first line of the text file):

```
set /p Var=<resultat.txt
echo %Var%
cmd /k
```

It just echoes nothing, saying "ECHO is on".

Also, if you use "type" to print the contents of the text file, there is weird spacing, suggesting it's not properly being processed.

**Attempted solution [1] - Powershell**

After research, I found that powershell can convert txt encodings, using the following method:

```
Get-Content -Path "path\file.txt" | Out-File -FilePath "path\new_file.txt" -Encoding <encoding>
```

Using Notepad++, I did some research, what encoding do I need to attain?

UTF-8 (no BOM), which is equivalent to "ANSI" in Notepad, is the encoding I need, loading text files to variables, and the "type" command, both work flawlessly when this encoding is used. How do I know? If I open the piped text file in Notepad, and resave as "ANSI" encoding, everything works flawlessly.

```
-Encoding ascii
```

...Is the option which should have worked, as this produces a result in UTF-8 (no BOM), but it seems to be unable to handle UTF-16 LE source encoding format, and does not produce useable output. When I opened the resultant file in Notepad++ it identified it as UTF-16 LE "Unix", which was odd.

Funny enough: if I resave piped txt file as "unicode" in Notepad, this produces a UTF-16 LE BOM file, which works with the above conversion parameter to produce a perfect UTF-8 file. At this point, I extended my research to also ask the question "How can I add BOM to UTF-16 LE encoding?" As I could combine such knowledge with the powershell knowledge. However, spoiler alert: I was unsuccessful in finding a decent answer.

```
-Encoding utf8
```

...Is another similar option, but it produces a UTF-8 BOM file (the equivalent of saving as "UTF-8" in Notepad), this produces an output with corruption.

**So to sum up:**

I am looking for a command line tool/method (open or proprietary, 1st or 3rd party), to be able to achieve a convesion as follows:

1. UTF-16 LE - Windows(CR LF) straight to UTF-8 - Windows(CR LF)
2. UTF-16 LE - Windows(CR LF) to UTF-16 LE BOM - Windows(CR LF)

Comment: Does [Converting text file to UTF-8 on Windows command prompt - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1163753/converting-text-file-to-utf-8-on-windows-command-prompt/1163765#1163765) answer your question?

Comment: Are you using the [chcp command](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)? Try `chcp 437` (United States) to see if with it the `program` generates an ANSI file.

Comment: @DavidPostill that result produces a UTF-8 BOM result which is not displayed properly and gives garbled cmd result. But thanks for the reply. "Set-Content" certainly looked different to "Out-File" which I demonstrated here, but it seems it does the same thing

Comment: @harrymc I did briefly come across some solutions which used "chcp" however I didn't have luck using them, but from the sounds of it, maybe it deserves revisiting. Could you potentially provide a working example, or link one? I will do some research later today when I have time. if I run "chcp" it tells me I am using code page 866.

Comment: [Code page 866](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866) is "DOS Cyrillic Russian", so there is no reason that it will generate UTF16. However, try putting the line `chcp 437` before the command.

Comment: @harrymc, Hi again - if I put aside batch files for now, and type "chcp 437" in cmd, to change my active code page, then within the same cmd window, I perform my "pipe" from the pogram to a text file, it still produces a UTF-16 LE result,if I "type" that txt file within the same window, it still comes out with weird spacing. I assumed that might have worked, to be honest! I can run chcp after that in the same window and it assures me it's using 437. Do I maybe need to do everything in one line of input?

Comment: No, evidently this is not a matter of the code-page - it's the program that generates the output in UTF16. Do you control the program, or does it have any settings for that?

Comment: @harrymc Ok, I am using Frank Westlake's "recycle.exe" (https://web.archive.org/web/20160814031010/http://ss64.net/westlake/xp/index.html). I think development of this program is already finished, I am not sure that it's output can be changed in such a specific manner. I can run the program without piping, and it outputs things fine in CMD. I just thought, if we knew the txt format that is outputted, surely there is a method for converting. notepad.exe can do this, I would have throught there'd be a cli program that can also do it.

Comment: @harrymc I am almost relieved that the encoding is set by the program, I just tried "netstat > text.txt" and it produced something n++ considered to be "ansi", so luckily (or unluckily) it's just this particular program I need to worry about. But as said earlier, I believe I have no method for altering it's output encoding, only dealing with it "after the fact". I have learned something, so thanks for that.

Comment: This code might work to convert the UTF16 file : `type utf16.txt >ansi.txt`. If it works, I'll put up an answer.

Comment: @harrymc Hey again! Annoyingly the resultant file was in the same encoding as the original, and performed equally poorly in cmd...  I am wondering, the UTF-16 LE files created by recycle.exe can be displayed in cmd via type (albeit, with weird spacing, but there is no real corruption), they can even be "type"d to a brand new text document (of the same encoding), my only issue is that storing txt file contents as a variable don't work. Could I find a way to parse the document to just return valid, allowed characters? Does that work? Maybe that would then be saveable in a normal encoding

Comment: @harrymc Hey I just wanted you to know:  weirdly enough that chcp article you linked on ss64, happens to mention that "type" is one of the only commands that "allows reading and writing (UTF-16LE / BOM) files". If I click on the page dedicated to "type", down at the bottom there is a demo example of a batch file that converts "an ASCII (Windows1252) file into a Unicode (UCS-2 le) text file". So TYPE and cmd trickery can be used to convert encoding of a text file! I have no idea if their example can be reverse engineered, my batch knowledge hardly extends that far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Path of least resistance: use libiconv for Windows**

After about a day of searching (back when the question was asked), I noticed that Stackoverflow had a tag called [utf16-le] and I decided it would be worth my time to go through all of the threads using this tag.

I found a solution which shows off a program called "iconv", and even the full command needed to carry out the conversion. Unlike the powershell method, you need to accurately specify input encoding as well as the output encoding, but also unlike the powershell method, it produces a good result.

Here is the helpful thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287713/using-iconv-to-convert-from-utf-16le-to-utf-8

iconv is not a Windows utility, but it was apparently ported to Windows, and whilst the question linked above was asked with the [Linux] tag, one of the answers contained an example which is somehow entirely compatible with Windows:

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 infile > outfile
```

I downloaded the files from here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/libiconv/1.9.2-1/

I only needed the "bin" (binary) and "dep" (dependencies), extract the contents of both into the same folder, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The `type` command will work if the UTF16 file does not contain a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark):

```
type utf16.txt >ascii.txt
```

But as in your case the generated file does have a BOM, a sure-fire
method for converting the file uses PowerShell:

```
powershell "Get-Content 'utf16.txt' | Out-File 'ascii.txt' -Encoding ascii"
```

Notice the use of two types of quotes to avoid the need to escape the
inner quotes.

Comment: Hello! Do you happen to know if this solution differs from the powershell method I mentioned in my original post? It's just, on the surface it looks very similar. Just to be clear (I tried to make sure my post was detailed, but I considered less the prospect of making that information easily understandable.. so I apologise), the file created by piping recycle.exe output to a txt file, is UTF-16 LE, without BOM. That is the format I need to convert from. When I ran powershell's get-content out-file, it was in a seperate PS1 file, your suggestion is to do it within batch without a "middle-file"?

Comment: I'm only making suggestions, the decision is yours what to do.

Comment: It's fair enough, no problem, I am just looking at this and it looks like something I've tried already, that's all. I am not at home currently so will only be able to try this later today. Just to clarify, you suggest running "powershell -command "command in quotes"" from cmd/batch - right? On an unrelated note - do you think it's worth me tidying up the question, and maybe opening it in stackoverflow? Is this "superuser" material or more advanced?

Comment: Hey again - I found a solution: someone on stackoverflow had the exact same query many years ago, and they were recommended to use gnuwin32 ("iconv") program. I was able to successfully use this program via CMD to get the correct conversion. Would you be offended if I were to delete my thread, as I see it as absolutely redundant now...

Comment: I won't be offended, but a thread on stackoverflow doesn't mean that your post is redundant. You should rather post here your own answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - to be fair, the original thread I found was not easy to find, and 100% evaded search results (I went through ALL threads under the [utf16le] tag on SO manually). In that case, would it be OK if I also re-wrote the main post to be more concise and to the point? Given how much of your own time you volunteered to helping on this thread, I think it's fair to ask you first. Thanks

Comment: You wish to modify my answer or your post ? Go ahead, no problem.

Comment: I think you have this backward. On my 8.1 (I don't have 7) `type` of UTF16LE _with BOM_ converts to ASCII, but UTF16LE _without BOM_ (which OP has) keeps the null byte after each character which on console displays as a space, and blanks out the first real character; if `>file` it is still UTF16LE not ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /v "" sourcefile > destinationFile
```

this will read the contents of a sourcefile, and print any line that DOES NOT match "" (nothing) - thereby printing the contents of the entire file.

the find command seems to parse UTF-16 fine for me, and also happens to output plain ascii, so, your destination file will contain the same text as source, but will be ascii.

Answer (score 0):

For the "add missing BOM" option: I don't have 7, but in 8.1 (or 10):

- open notepad, don't enter anything, and save as Unicode (UTF16LE in 10); this creates a file containing *only* littleendian BOM
- `copy bomfile+bomless_utf16le newfile`

The result works for me with `type` and powershell `get-content`.

But it's not as devious as Charles' `find /v ""`!